# Example of $D$ such that $A=$ is an upper bounded set and $D=\{a^2\in A\}$ is not.

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Consider $A\subset\Bbb{R}$ an upper bounded set and $D=\{a^2\in A\}$. What would be an example such that $D$ is not upper bounded?

Comment: Consider the half-line $A=(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: A is the set of negative integers